# How to use set as a list in java without copying data from set to list

Tags: java, list, set

I want to use set as a list in java without copying data from set to list.

Comment: Answer depends on what you mean by "*use set as a list*". Please [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: Your requirement is very odd since a `Set` doesn't behave like a `List`. If you're looking for a `Set` that maintains the order in which the data was entered then use `LinkedHashSet`. Apart of that, I don't really understand the second part of your *question*: *without copying data from set to list*.

Comment: As these are different data structures and behave differently you have to copy on to the other to change it's behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean you want to dump the contents from a `set` into a `list`, without having to do a `loop` over the entire `set` adding the contents one by one. If this is the case, you can use the `List.addAll()` function in the `List` implementation. It can be used like:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
List<String> setToList = new ArrayList<String>();
setToList.addAll(set);
```

A full example of using this could be run with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("Some String");
    set.add("Another String");
    set.add("etc");

    for(String s : set){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    List<String> setToList = new ArrayList<String>();
    setToList.addAll(set);

    for(String s : setToList){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `List<String> setToList = new ArrayList<String>(set);`?

Comment: OP wrote "without copying".